# Matlab - Gaussian mixture and Fuzzy C-means less accurate than K-means on high-dimensional data (image of 26-dimension vectors)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, cluster-analysis, k-means

I took the `matlab` code from this tutorial [Texture Segmentation Using Gabor Filters](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/texture-segmentation-using-gabor-filters.html).

To test `clustering` algorithms on the resulting multi-dimensional `texture` responses to `gabor filters`, I applied `Gaussian Mixture` and `Fuzzy C-means` instead of the `K-means` to compare their results (number of clusters = 2 in all of the cases):

#### Original image:

[image: Original image]

#### K-means clusters:

```
L = kmeans(X, 2, 'Replicates', 5);
```

[image: kmeans]

#### GMM clusters:

```
options = statset('MaxIter',1000);
gmm = fitgmdist(X, 2, 'Options', options);
L = cluster(gmm, X);
```

[image: gmm]

#### Fuzzy C-means:

```
[centers, U] = fcm(X, 2);
[values indexes] = max(U);
```

[image: Fuzzy C-means]

What I've found weird in this case is that `K-means` clusters are more accurate than those extracted using `GMM` and `Fuzzy C-means`.

Can anyone explain to me if the high-dimensionality (`L x W x 26`: 26 is the number of `gabor filters` used) of the data given as input to the `GMM` and the `Fuzzy C-means` classifiers is what's causing the clustering to be less accurate?

In other words is the `GMM` and the `Fuzzy C-means` clustering more sensitive to the dimensionality of the data, than `K-means` is?

Comment: I don't have the right toolboxes for this, but here are a few observations. All methods are sensitive to initialization, but k-means is *cheating* by using 5 `'Replicates'` and higher quality initialization (k-means++). k-means is `GMM` under a spherical-covariance assumption, so in theory it shouldn't do much better. I think most of the discrepancy comes down to initialization. You should be able to test this by using the k-means result as initial conditions for `GMM`.

Comment: @kmac You might be right, running those clustering algorithms multiple times seems to yield a different result on every execution. Could you please write it as an answer to receive the bounty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad the comment was useful, here are my observations in answer form.

Each of these methods are sensitive to initialization, but `k-means` is *cheating* by using 5 `'Replicates'` and higher quality initialization (`k-means++`). The rest of the methods appear to be using a single random initialization.

`k-means` is `GMM` if you force spherical covariance. So in theory, it shouldn't do much better (it might do slightly better if the true covariance was in fact spherical).

I think most of the discrepancy comes down to initialization. You should be able to test this by using the k-means result as initial conditions for the other algorithms. Or as you tried, run several times using different random seeds and check if there is more variation in `GMM` and `Fuzzy C-means` than there is in `k-means`.